# Installation did not succeed. The application could not be installed. Installation failed due to: 'device offline'

Tags: android, build, android-emulator, adb, emulation

In *android studio 3.6.3*

This error indicates when I click on the Run button to install the program on the emulator.

> Installation did not succeed. The application could not be installed.
>   Installation failed due to: 'device offline'

Comment: Update to Android Studio 4

Comment: This was related to adb and it had a problem @MMG

Answer (score 2):

I was using the emulator. I just close the **Android Studio** and then opened it again. The issue was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of searching, I found out that the ***adb*** had a problem and the emulator was turned off incorrectly.
I entered these commands in the *cmd* and the above error was fixed.

```
adb kill-server 

adb start-server 

adb connect [192.168.162.101]:5555 

adb devices 
List of devices attached [192.168.162.101]:5555  device
```

***NOTE***

This IP is 192.168.162.101, which has an emulator itself. If you want to run the emulator manually, ***you must get your emulator IP and replace it with 192.168.162.101***, otherwise it should automatically follow. Implement the first two commands of the emulator on the adb

Answer (score 0):

Disconnect your phone and connect again. This was worked for me.